# How to modify lambda statement to start at lists index position and return that position

Tags: c#, propertyinfo

I have the following function that searches a class' property values for a text match, if any of them have a match it returns true.

```
private static List<Func<Type, string>> _properties;
private static Type _itemType;

public static bool Match(string searchTerm)
{
    bool match = _properties.Select(prop => prop(_itemType)).Any(value => value != null && value.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower()));
    return match;
}
```

The _properties list is in the order of the bound properties on a DataGrid's columns.
_itemType is the class type.

What I would like to do is, continue searching for the text, but, in addition change this  so that it will start at a particular property's index in the list and return either, the index of the first property match it comes to or null.

The start of the function will look like so:

```
public static int Match(int start_index, string searchTerm)
```

Could use some help in figuring out the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: Understanding this right, you want to provide an `out int` that fills that up with the offset of the first match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want ?

```
 public static int? Match(int start_index, string searchTerm)
    {
        var wanted = _properties
            .Select((prop,i) => new { Index = i, Item = prop(_itemType) })
            .Skip(start_index)
            .FirstOrDefault(value => value.Item != null && value.Item.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower()));
        return wanted==null ? null : (int?)wanted.Index;
    }
```

1. Use select with the second index parameter and store it in an
   anonymous type.
2. Then skip past the number specified in
   'start_index'.
3. Then search the remainder and if one is found, return
   the original index.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `.Skip(int)` function if you want to start it at an exact offset, e.g.

```
return _properties.Skip(start_index).Sele[...]
```

If you want to return the index of the first occuring element, use `.IndexOf()` instead of `.Any()`

Since `.IndexOf()` returns -1 on no results, if you wish to return a null, you can do so by checking if the value returned equals -1:

```
if (result == -1)
    return null;
```

Please notice that you will have to make the return value a nullable int (= `int?`) for it to be able to return a null.

*EDIT*

My apologies, `IEnumerable`s do not have the `IndexOf()` function as there's no index in one. You can try using `.TakeWhile(bool).Count()` to get an index.
An alternative would be to use `.ToList().IndexOf()`, if you really want to use it, but it'd be much slower since you'd have to parse the entire object.

Comment: Well rounded answer and remembering the nullable return value thanks!

Comment: Have I got this right? As it does not work with .IndexOf replacing .Any: _properties.Skip(startPropIndex).Select(prop => prop(_itemType)).Any(value => value != null && value.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower()));

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see any IndexOf method in System.Linq extensions.  Another point about this answer (assuming IndexOf exists somewhere else) is that you should remember to add start_index to the result.

Comment: @Hank Read my edit, I forgot `IndexOf()` wasn't a part of `IEnumerable`s.